# Passing a typed value to a link as a parameter

Tags: jquery

Trying to build a parameter url with the same text been typed into this text box. Not working is here a better why to do this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#texto").on('keypress change', function(event) {
        var data=$(this).val();
        $("#go").text(data);
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" value="" id="texto"/>
    <a href="home.php?where=<div id='go'></div>">Home</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: $("#go") will not be available, since it is passed as a query param

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a div inside an href attribute. I think what you're after is:

```
$("#texto").on('keyup change', function(event) {
  $(this).next('a').attr('href','home.php?where=' + $(this).val());
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jr5bmg9r/)**

Comment: If you have another question, please create a new question, don't ask it as a comment to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `attr` of `a tag` with input value. Html not allowed to put any element inside the `attribute` of any tag.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#texto").keyup(function(){
    $("#go").attr('href','home.php?where=' + $(this).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" value="" id="texto"/>
    <a id='go' href="#">Home</a>
  </body>
</html>
```